# Manually print Cucumber table diff

Tags: ruby, cucumber

We wrap table assertions in retry blocks when we update a resource via an async angular action. Reason being, the browser updates are *sometimes* slower than the test runner's assertions.

Wrapping these assertions, however, doesn't print the diff to console.

Output w/o retries (pretty!)

[image]

Output w/ retry (no diff)

[image]

What I'd like to do is catch the exception (Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different) from within the retry block and manually  print the table diff to console and reraise the exception to trigger the retry. The code below "works", but I can't seem to figure out how to manually print the table diff to console.

```
Then(/^I should see the following self\-reported trades:$/) do |table|
  retry_quickly do
    rows = find("table#trades-table").all('tr')
    actual_table = rows.map { |r| r.all('th,td').map { |c| c.text.strip } }
    begin
      table.diff!(actual_table)
    rescue Cucumber::Ast::Table::Different => e
      # puts table diff
      raise e
    end
  end
end
```